# In Jira I want a Kanban board where all issues belong to an Epic with a status of "In Progress"

Tags: jira-agile

I'm using Jira Agile, and I'm trying to use a JQL search to select issues where the owning Epic has a particular status value.
I've tried the linkedIssuesOf() function, but that doesn't seem to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible using JQL only without some scripting addon.